# Deployment: Amazon Web Services - Taking too long to respond

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, backend

I've just finished setting up my site on a free Amazon Web Services EC2 Ubuntu server.

I'm not very knowledgeable in deployment, and I'm not 100% clear on what Nginx or gunicorn even is, but I'm following a tutorial to launch a Django project.

While doing things the same exact way, having no errors, I have noticed that sometimes I will go to my site and get 'refused to connect' or 'taking too long to respond.'

One of my previous projects had no issue, one of them never loaded the page, and the last one I did gave me this problem which was cured by rebooting the server.
I've rebooted the server several times as well as deactivated and reactivated the venv (as a classmate suggested) but it isn't working. I noticed that last night my terminal just kept taking forever to load and the Amazon web services site was just being slow as well.

Is this just Amazon's fault? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score -1):

You are spinning up your server. You are responsible to manage it.

There are a couple of things you need to check. The problem could be service may not be listening on a different port (check on IP as well), inbound and outbound security groups might not be configured right.

Amazon is not responsible for anything you do with their resources. It is a  company to provide resources to simplify your business.

You can read AWS SLA here,
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/